# Using custom CRM with GOautodial

Tags: java, asterisk

What is the best way to integrate GOautodial with a custom java based CRM, so that CRM can use GOautodial's telephony services and functionalities?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

GOautodial is a fork of VICIdial. VICIdial has two APIs:

NON_AGENT_API: Functions that are made in the back office (adding users, load leads, search for recordings, etc.).

AGENT_API: Functions the agent do while in their screen (pausing, hanging up, disposition, manual dial, etc.).

These are all done via GET requests passing arguments in the URL (key=value), for example the next three lines hangup, disposition and pause the agent:

```
http://server/agc/api.php?source=test&user=6666&pass=1234&agent_user=1000&function=external_hangup&value=1
http://server/agc/api.php?source=test&user=6666&pass=1234&agent_user=1000&function=external_status&value=A
http://server/agc/api.php?source=test&user=6666&pass=1234&agent_user=1000&function=external_pause&value=PAUSE
```

I've had customers that fully operate VICIdial outside the agent window, you should be able to achieve the same with GOautodial. If you need any help let me know.